# Timer in Win service doesnt call elapsed event

Tags: c#, timer

I'm writing Windows Service that calls for method after defined period of time (for now its 20 seconds). Everything was working fine until it didn't. Can't seem to find the cause of the problem.
Service seems to start and stop properly giving log entry, but it seems like it doesnt call for elapsed event.

```
public partial class UssPwdSyncService : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer timer1 = null; 
    public UssPwdSyncService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();
            this.timer1.Interval = 20000;
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_tick);
            timer1.Enabled = true;

            LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs("Service has started! LOg!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs(ex);
        }
    }
    private void timer1_tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
        foreach (ConnectionStringSettings cStr in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
        {
            string name = cStr.Name;
            string connString = cStr.ConnectionString;
            string provider = cStr.ProviderName;

            LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs(name + " " + connString + " " + provider);
        }
        LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs("This does something!");
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs("Service has stoped!");
    }
}
```

Could someone point out what am I missing?

Comment: Does the event fire at all? Or just once? If the latter try setting AutoReset to true.

Comment: @PaulF - the default for `AutoReset` is `true`, and you can see them `new`ing up the timer just above.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: you are right, I misread the docs.

Comment: If you put a log line on the first line of `timer1_tick` does it get logged? Perhaps it is firing but `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection` or your `foreach` is throwing a exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved try catch to timer1_tick method.
This is the right place to exception check.

You can be throwing an exception o timer1_tick peace of code.
You have `connectionStrings` sections?

> Note: i prefer to use `Start` and `Stop` methods instead of `Enabled = true`
>   and `Enabled = false`.
>   Two ways are right.

Try this:

```
public partial class UssPwdSyncService : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer timer1 = null; 
    public UssPwdSyncService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.timer1 = new Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = 20000;
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_tick);
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.timer1.Start();
        LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs("Service has started! LOg!");
    }
    private void timer1_tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
            foreach (ConnectionStringSettings cStr in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
            {
                string name = cStr.Name;
                string connString = cStr.ConnectionString;
                string provider = cStr.ProviderName;

                LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs(name + " " + connString + " " + provider);
            }
            LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs("This does something!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs(ex);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.timer1.Stop();
        LogHandling.WriteErrorLogs("Service has stoped!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you changed? Why do you believe it will fix the problem? "Try this" does not an answer make.

Comment: Explanation of this ??

Comment: I added to the answer. I believe the error is on timer1_tick. and then he is not logging because an exception is throwing before logging.

Comment: Yes, this is where exceptions was thrown. I was searching in wrong place. Silly, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the Timer in `System.Timers`.  You need to call the timer's `Start()` method.

Comment: According to the docs _You can also start timing by setting Enabled to true._  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Indeed. The more common "bug" I've seen on SO is people both setting `Enabled` to `true` *and* calling `Start()`. (It doesn't produce erroneous behaviour, but it is redundant)

Comment: Right. Call the start method though

Comment: See [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs,282)

Comment: They both (Start() vs Enabled) do the same thing. Some people just like methods, other like properties.